# How to implement rel=author on a page with multiple authors?

Tags: forum, rel-author

I have a forum, and I would like to add `rel=author` to my pages. However, each page has multiple authors, and I'm not sure how I should implement `rel=author` if I have multiple authors.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe someone is still seeing this question, so it could be useful to point out that Google no more supports Google Authorship

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en

And it encourages the use of structured data.

So, no more need to add `rel=author` for Google. It still exists as microformat and could be used by other applications.
You can still add where you are author through Google+ for social purposes.

But that doesn't mean Google no more recognizes author of a post. It analyzes structured data, bylines, citations, as always it did.

Answer (score 4):

I used the instructions on the article [How To Implement Rel=Author](http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/how-to-implement-rel-author) for creating my page. The only difference is that I had two `rel=author` links instead of one. I then tested the page with Google's [rich snippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), and the first author that was linked was displayed as if it were the only author. *The second author was not displayed at all*.

Multiple `rel=author` links is something that I think Google should recognize, as pages like forums and wikis usually have more than one author.

Comment: Pages like forums and wikis can have dozens of authors on a single page, which Google would be unable to display in any useful form. I would argue that `rel=author` is inappropriate for pages with THAT many authors.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any `author`-specific information, but the HTML specs do allow you to define more than one link with the same relationship, e.g.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="//de.example.com/my/page.htm">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="//uk.example.com/my/page.htm">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="/my/page.rss">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="/my/page.xml">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/pdf" href="/my/page.pdf">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/pdf" media="print" href="/my/print-page.pdf">
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="/my/mobile/page.htm">
```

I would assume that the same could be done with the `author` relationship.

Comment: do you know if Google will recognize it, though?

Comment: @Christofian: That, I do not know. Maybe you can try it and let us know? =P

Comment: I'll try it then, and I'll let you know how it goes...

Comment: Result of my experiment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/25185/6901

Answer (score 3):

According to the [HTML5 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-author):

> The author keyword may be used with link, a, and area elements. This
>   keyword creates a hyperlink.
>
> For a and area elements, the author keyword indicates that the
>   referenced document provides further information about the author of
>   the nearest article element ancestor of the element defining the
>   hyperlink, if there is one, or of the page as a whole, otherwise.

While the specification does not indicate a resolution for multiple authors specified at the HTML5 document level, the element level does provide support for multiple authors within a single HTML5 document (which should cover your forum's needs).

Answer (score 2):

Testing a page on the testing tool i saw this:

> Note: The testing tool currently only checks the first rel=author link listed on a webpage for a link to a Google+ profile [...]. It's possible that authorship may in fact be working for this page because of other rel=author links on the page. To verify that authorship is working on this page, please ensure the first profile listed on the site links to the appropriate Google+ profile.