# Long after the demise of Google Authorship, is it now both valid and viable for a document to include multiple <link rel="author"> links?

Tags: links, rel-author

When **Google Authorship** was very much still a thing several years ago, the conclusion was that it was better not to include more than one `<link rel="author">` on any given page.

See:

- [2012 - How to implement rel="author" on a page with multiple authors?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/how-to-implement-rel-author-on-a-page-with-multiple-authors/25185#25185)
- [2013 - Is Google OK with multiple rel="author" links?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47349/is-google-ok-with-multiple-rel-author-links)

**Google Authorship** is now a distant memory (Mountain View stopped using it several centuries ago in 2016) but I'm concerned that there may still be something invalid or nonsensical about including more than one `<link rel="author">` in the `<head>` of a given document.

My use case involves referencing both an **About Page** and **humans.txt**:

```
<link rel="author" href="https://example.com/about-us/" />
<link rel="author" href="https://example.com/humans.txt" type="text/plain" />
```

Is there anything - I can't find explicit confirmation - from the **WHAT-WG** to confirm that this is valid usage?

Or is there a viable alternative to using more than one `<link rel="author">` element?

Comment: Using meta links is only going to bloat your page unless you know of some use for them.  The only reason to include them that I know of would have been because Google used them for the rich author result.  Is there some other reason to have author links now?

Comment: Hah. Yes, because i) there are documents where authorship is relevant data and ii) Google isn't the only consumer of meta-information.

Comment: I agree with you, @StephenOstermiller, that the meta `<link>` elements appearing in any given document should be selected carefully.

Answer (score 1):

While `rel="author"` is deprecated and out of use, information about an author is still mandatory. [Specially for AMP-pages is an author a required property](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article?hl=en#amp).

[For non-AMP pages](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article?hl=en#non-amp) is the author-property doesn't mentioned as required - but i personally very recommend to use it.

Information about an author serves as an important trust signal. I very recommend to use the author property as `Person` or `Organization` type and provide additional info, like links to social network profiles, so Google is able to validate the author's personality.

Comment: Thank you for this, @Evgeniy, but this answer doesn't relate to the question: _"[...] is it now both valid and viable for a document to **include multiple** `<link rel=“author”>` links?"_ (Also I'm not sure `rel="author"` is deprecated - we both know that Google isn't currently using it, but... Google isn't the only consumer of meta-data).

Comment: it is as much valid as any word without semantic meaning. You can use it once or twice or as much as you want - no meaning multiplied by any number equals no meaning. Nobody beside Google was consuming this attribute, nobody consumes it after Google deprecated it.

Comment: Re: _"nobody consumes it"_ - [**humans.txt**](http://humanstxt.org/) consumes `<link rel="author">`. Also, I accept that if no-one is looking for `<link>` then it has no meaning - but when someone is looking for the `<link>` in a consistent manner and for a consistent purpose, _that's_ what gives it meaning.

Comment: what consumes `humans.txt` and for which purpose?

Comment: I'll clarify: the [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/) protocol invites you to use `rel=author`. See: [If possible, you can also add an author tag to the `<head>` of the site: `<link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="http://domain/humans.txt" />`](http://humanstxt.org/)

Comment: if you write for humans, why should you care about markup? Write just `I'm the author, my name is Bob`... I really don't get your point

Comment: I guess if you have questions about the `humans.txt` protocol, your questions are best directed to the authors of that protocol.

Comment: Maybe i'll open you a big mistery, which doesn't let you sleep tight, but somebody must do it. You should know: `humans.txt` is absolutely useless, in any terms, for any purpose, in any technical setup and environment.

Comment: I imagine it will help you more to address this sentiment directly to the authors of the `humans.txt` protocol.